# How to check for and use input from a different methood

Tags: java

I am making a game and a the end of the game I want it to call the user by the name that they put in,, this is the code I have.

```
private static final Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {// follow the prompts.//

    System.out.println("Hello user! what is your name? ");
    String Name = console.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Really? " + Name + " is too weird to be a real name.");
    confirmation();
    Mascot();
    System.out.println("Thank you for playing the demo");

    console.close();
}

public static void confirmation() {

    System.out.print("is that REALLY your name? (type Y/N) ");
    String yN = console.nextLine();
    String a = yN;
    if (a.toLowerCase().contains("y")) {
        System.out.println("I still dont belive you, so you will have to answer 3 riddles before you can continue to the game");
    } else {
        calledIt();
    }

}

public static void calledIt() {

    System.out.println("I knew it!");
    System.out.print("whats your real name? ");
    String realName = console.nextLine();
    System.out.println(
            "" + realName + " sounds like a real name, but you lied the first time so you will need to answer riddles 3 to continue to the game");

}

public static boolean Mascot() {

    System.out.println("what Is our school mascot?");
    String b = console.nextLine();
    if (b.toLowerCase().contains("tiger")) {
        System.out.println("Good, next riddle.");
        System.out.println("What runs around the whole yard without moving?");
        String c = console.nextLine();
        if (c.toLowerCase().contains("fence")) {
            System.out.println("Good, next riddle.");
            System.out.println("What goes on four feet in the morning, two feet at noon, and three feet in the evening? ");
            String d = console.nextLine();
            if (d.toLowerCase().contains("man")) {
                System.out.println("You, have sucsefully passed the third riddle");
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("You have failed");
                return false;
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("You have failed");
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("You have failed");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want for it to at the end print * user's name*, you have successfully passed the third riddle.
but it needs to be able to weather the first name was kept, or if this sequence was used.

```
public static void calledIt() {

    System.out.println("I knew it!");
    System.out.print("whats your real name? ");
    String realName = console.nextLine();
    System.out.println(
            "" + realName + " sounds like a real name, but you lied the first time so you will need to answer riddles 3 to continue to the game");

}
```

and if it has been activated it needs to use the new name.

Comment: Make your method(s) return a string?

Comment: Another option is to move the declaration of  `Name` out to CLASS level (the same place where your `console` variable is declared) and make it STATIC: `private static String name;`. Then change `String Name = ` to `Name = `. Now you can access  that `Name` variable from all of the methods to either retrieve it or update it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change return type of calledIt() to String and return realName from this method
2. Change return type of confirmation() to String. Initialize a String (String name = null). In the else part, assign the value returned from calledIt() to this string (String name = calledIt()). Return name.
3. In main, if the value returned from confirmation() is not null, update Name with this new value.
4. Pass the Name as input to Mascot method. For this, you have to update the Mascot method to accept a String as input.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable into confirmation() and calledIt() like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {// follow the prompts.//

    System.out.println("Hello user! what is your name? ");
    String Name = console.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Really? " + Name + " is too weird to be a real name.");
    confirmation(Name);
    Mascot();
    System.out.println("Thank you for playing the demo");

    console.close();
}
    
public static void confirmation(String name) {
    
        System.out.print("is that REALLY your name? (type Y/N) ");
        String yN = console.nextLine();
        String a = yN;
        if (a.toLowerCase().contains("y")) {
            System.out.println("I still dont belive you, so you will have to answer 3 riddles before you can continue to the game");
        } else {
            calledIt(name);
        }
    
    }

     public static void calledIt(String realName){
            System.out.println("I knew it!");
            System.out.print("whats your real name? ");
            System.out.println(
                    "" + realName + " sounds like a real name, but you lied the first time so you will need to answer riddles 3 to continue to the game");
        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following change:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { // follow the prompts.//
    System.out.println("Hello user! What is your name? ");
    String name = console.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Really? " + name + " is too weird to be a real name.");
    System.out.print("Is that REALLY your name? (type Y/N) ");
    String yN = console.nextLine();
    String a = yN;
    if (a.toLowerCase().contains("y")) {
        System.out.println("I still don't believe you, so you will have to answer 3 riddles before you can continue to the game");
    } else {
        System.out.println("I knew it!");
        System.out.print("Whats your real name? ");
        name = console.nextLine();
        System.out.println(
            "" + name + " sounds like a real one, but you lied the first time so you will need to answer riddles 3 to continue to the game");
    }

    mascot(name);
    System.out.println("Thank you for playing the demo");

    console.close();
}

public static boolean mascot(String name) {

    System.out.println("what Is our school mascot?");
    String b = console.nextLine();
    if (b.toLowerCase().contains("tiger")) {
        System.out.println("Good, next riddle.");
        System.out.println("What runs around the whole yard without moving?");
        String c = console.nextLine();
        if (c.toLowerCase().contains("fence")) {
            System.out.println("Good, next riddle.");
            System.out.println("What goes on four feet in the morning, two feet at noon, and three feet in the evening? ");
            String d = console.nextLine();
            if (d.toLowerCase().contains("man")) {
                System.out.println(name + ", you have successfully passed the third riddle");
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("You have failed");
                return false;
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("You have failed");
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("You have failed");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the proper approach since it  does not answer the question

Comment: Hi @WillEvers! Please, double-check the description of the question: I want for it to at the end print * user's name*, you have successfully passed the third riddle. but it needs to be able to weather the first name was kept, or if this sequence was used.

So the main change here is:
`System.out.println(name + ", you have successfully passed the third riddle");`
Which will print the gamer's name after solving all the steps.

Comment: the question is "How to check for and use input from a different methood?"

Comment: @WillEvers I do need it answered in a way that fulfills what Alex said